# Bot Framework Custom Action and custom ArrayExpression property

Tags: properties, frameworks, bots

I’m building a bot using **Microsoft’s Bot Framework Composer**. To extend the composer’s standard features, I also built some **Custom Actions**, including one that needs input in the form of an array of a specific type.
Here is the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.botframework.com/schemas/component/v1.0/component.schema",
  "$role": "implements(Microsoft.IDialog)",
  "title": "AdvancePropertyTest",
  "description": "Test advanced properties in for custom actions.",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "skillSelectors": {
      "$ref": "schema:#/definitions/arrayExpression",
      "title": "SkillSelector Items",
      "description": "SkillSelector Items.",
      "items": {
        "title": "SkillSelector Item",
        "description": "SkillSelector Item.",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "title": "Key",
            "description": "The skill key to query against.",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "operator": {
            "title": "Operator",
            "description": "Describes how the value of the label is compared to the value defined on the label selector.",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "Equal",
              "NotEqual",
              "LessThan",
              "LessThanEqual",
              "GreaterThan",
              "GreaterThanEqual"
            ],
            "default": "Equal"
          },
          "value": {
            "title": "Value",
            "description": "The value to compare against the actual label value with the given operator.",
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which, in the composer, results in:
[Composer action with custom properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QWA1.png)

So far, so good.
Now, in the dialog's code, in order to retrieve the input data, this is what I did:

```
[Serializable]
public class SkillSelector
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}


public class AdvancedPropertyTest : Dialog
{
    [JsonProperty("skillSelectors")]
    public ArrayExpression<SkillSelector> SkillSelectors { get; set; }
    //public ArrayExpression<Metadata> SkillSelectors { get; set; }


    public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var skillSelectors = SkillSelectors?.GetValue(dc.State);
        // some code

        return await dc.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error message once I run it:

```
AdvancedProperties.dialog error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ‘AdaptiveExpressions.Properties.ArrayExpression`1[SkillSelector]’ because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path ‘skillSelectors’, line 49, position 37.
```

Interesting fact, using class **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.MetaData** as the generic type in the **ArrayExpression** does the trick, but, of course, is not what I want.

Anyone an idea how to do this ?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found the solution. I added the following line in the **ConfigureServices** method of the BotComponent class:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddSingleton<DeclarativeType>(sp => new DeclarativeType<AdvancedPropertyTest>(nameof(AdvancedPropertyTest)));
    services.AddSingleton<JsonConverterFactory, JsonConverterFactory<ArrayExpressionConverter<SkillSelector>>>();
}
```

This adds the class **SkillSelector** in the **JsonSerializer**.

Hope this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties should derive from `AdaptiveExpressions.Properties`.
So instead of string use `StringExpression`, `BoolExpression`, and so on:

```
    [JsonProperty("businessUnitName")]
    public StringExpression BusinessUnitName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reloadData")]
    public BoolExpression ReloadData { get; set; }
```

To get the value:

```
BusinessUnitName.GetValue(dc.State)
```